# nextReportIndex should be non-null when sending an update

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

My Dataflow job failed with some cryptic message: `java.lang.NullPointerException: nextReportIndex should be non-null when sending an update`

Anyone have any ideas on what is that?

Apache Beam 2.5.0, Java SDK.

```
{
 insertId:  "5262797621023523329:315192:0:1849696"  
 jsonPayload: {
  exception:  "java.lang.NullPointerException: nextReportIndex should be non-null when sending an update
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.repackaged.com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:787)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.WorkItemStatusClient.createStatusUpdate(WorkItemStatusClient.java:236)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.WorkItemStatusClient.reportUpdate(WorkItemStatusClient.java:148)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.DataflowWorkProgressUpdater.reportProgressHelper(DataflowWorkProgressUpdater.java:90)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.WorkProgressUpdater.reportProgress(WorkProgressUpdater.java:299)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.WorkProgressUpdater.doNextUpdate(WorkProgressUpdater.java:252)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.WorkProgressUpdater.access$000(WorkProgressUpdater.java:41)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.WorkProgressUpdater$1.run(WorkProgressUpdater.java:231)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
"   
  job:  "2018-07-16_22_21_32-17936956005198631499"   
  logger:  "com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.WorkProgressUpdater"   
  message:  "Error reporting workitem progress update to Dataflow service: "   
  stage:  "s09"   
  thread:  "56"   
  work:  "2152469729993445222"
```

**UPDATE**:
Just randomly scrolling logs in Stackdriver above like 20 pages, I saw this error: `An OutOfMemoryException occurred. Consider specifying higher memory instances in PipelineOptions.` So probably they are related, although hasn't been reported on Dataflow UI.

Comment: Dataflow with python also does a poor job of reporting errors, logging a generic stacktrace instead of a stacktrace that goes into my code. One thing that works for me is wrapping up my `ParDo` / `DoFn`s with a try-catch. In the `catch` statement i print the stacktrace and reraise the error so that the true stacktrace appears in stackdriver.

Answer (score 1):

The Dataflow Monitoring Interface only shows an aggregation of errors produced in your pipeline. Some errors beneath this surface, such as OOM errors produced in a worker and not in your pipeline per se, are to be found through Stackdriver.

But, I would consider to raise OOM visibility from the Dataflow Monitoring Interface as a [Feature Request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187168&template=1162893). You can see [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/110246398) and [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/119494900) two feature requests to make shuffler errors more visible, either in the Monitoring Interface or in Stackdriver.

Comment: Thanks, starred them.

Answer (score 1):

The wording of this error is confusing but this error typically happens when a Dataflow worker becomes unresponsive for a prolonged period of time, and Dataflow service takes away the work that was delegated to this worker. Later, the Dataflow worker becomes responsive again, and tries to send progress updates, however Dataflow service has already delegated the same work item to a different worker, and rejects the progress update. Pipeline can still succeed in spite of these errors.

When this happens, you should try to identify why workers have become unresponsive. A typical scenario may be a prolonged garbage collection that monopolizes CPU resources. Typically the garbage collector is very fast even when clearing large amounts of memory but performs poorly when there is very little memory that can be freed.

GC actions are visualized in jvm-gc logger. A slow GC run may look like:

```
[Full GC (Ergonomics)  
[PSYoungGen: 4142045K->104507K(92054528K)] [ParOldGen: 97348766K->98843177K(109598208K)] 101490811K->98947684K(201652736K), [Metaspace: 70094K->70094K(81920K)], 206.1452492 secs] [Times: user=8260.91 sys=41.22, real=206.15 secs]
```

Note that this GC run took over 3 minutes, which is too long.

If you encounter a slow GC problem, try a worker machine type with a higher mem/vcpu ratio. If that fails, the follow up should be to make sure that pipeline has no known anti-patterns (such as loading the entire iterable from a GBK into memory, using a combiner which doesn't reduce inputs in size, like concatenation), and rule out memory leaks. A follow up investigation can be conducted via analyzing heap dumps.